# php - Adding new node to an xml string

Tags: php, xml

```
$result = "<QRYRESULT>
           <ISSUCCESS>Y</ISSUCCESS>
           <TRN_REF>2498297295729857927</TRN_REF>
           <WARNING>IF ANY WARNING</WARNING>
           </QRYRESULT>";
```

this is an XML string I am using. now I have to add a new node to this string (not a file). That is after adding the new node the XML string will look like the following. I am getting this XML string from another system in a variable so modifying the string manually is not an option.

```
$result = "<QRYRESULT>
           <ISSUCCESS>Y</ISSUCCESS>
           <TOKEN>some token</TOKEN>
           <TRN_REF>2498297295729857927</TRN_REF>
           <WARNING>IF ANY WARNING</WARNING>
           </QRYRESULT>";
```

how can I do that ??

Comment: First convert it into an XML object then add a node to it. Search PHP SimpleXML on SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Hi jishan, this question has been asked and answered a zillion times, see the link I posted above, try it and please come back with specific questions fitting the SO format.

Answer (score 0):

Use eg. [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourstring);
$xml->addChild('node_name', 'node_value');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score -2):

A variant without using XML and consistency check:

```
$result=str_replace("</ISSUCCESS>","</ISSUCCESS><TOKEN>some token</TOKEN>",$result);
```

Comment: this is messy and wide open to errors, I'd suggest to use an XML parser

Comment: It works in this context, fast, library-independent and not resource-intensive :)